# Is this the correct way of doing functional programming in Java?

Tags: java, coding-style, functional-programming

I'm trying to change my way of thinking to be more functional. Here's the sample code which I'm trying to change to be more functional.

```
 List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 6);

 ArrayList<Integer> multipledByTwo = new ArrayList<Integer>();

 for(Integer number : numbers) {
       multipledByTwo.add(number * 2);
 }
```

As far as I understand about functional java, the simplest rule which is no shared state. Am I correct to understand that this code there's a shared state which is `multipledByTwo`. Here's my version of functional java.

```
class MultipleByTwoIteration {
    public static List<Integer> map(List<Integer> numbers) {
        ArrayList<Integer> multipledByTwo = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(Integer number : numbers) {
            multipledByTwo.add(multipleByTwo(number));
        }

        return multipledByTwo;
    }

    private static Integer multipleByTwo(Integer number) {
        return number * 2;
    }
}
```

So I could just do

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 6);
List<Integer> multipledByTwo = MultipleByTwoIteration.map(numbers);
```

Am I correct that this is more of a functional way thinking? How do I improve my code if it's not functional?

Thanks.

Comment: Eh, a little, but doing "functional programming in Java" is somewhat awkward/nonsensical until Java 8 comes out.

Comment: Actually, Google Guava `Lists.transform` does just that. It's a Java way of map

Comment: Why don't you try a functional language instead?

Comment: Without multithreading there's no *shared state*.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more on that @MarkoTopolnik?

Comment: I suggest googling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is a bit more functional but not by much. Your map function is aware of the operation it will use for example; if you wanted a functional version of what you've written without using Guava or Java 8 I'd suggest something like this:

```java
public interface Function<S, T> {
    T apply(S in);
}

abstract class MappingClass<S, T> {
    protected List<T> map(List<S> list, Function<S, T> fun) {
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
        for(T item : list) {
            result.add(fun.apply(item));
        }
    }
}

class MultipleByTwoIteration extends MappingClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 6);

        List<Integer> multipledByTwo = map(numbers, 
                new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
            public Integer apply(Integer in) {
                return in * 2;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is part of what's being added in Java 8 or in Guava, but manually done. The `map` function knows nothing about what it's doing apart from that it's doing it to every element in the list past to it. The passed function has no idea of the context in which it is being used.  And therefore it can all be used in other contexts without having to modify anything except the main function.

**Edit:**
Just FYI, in Java 8 the same will be possible like this:

```java
class MultipleByTwoIteration extends MappingClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 6);

        List<Integer> multipledByTwo =
            numbers.stream().map(x -> x * 2).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

The `Function` interface, `map` function and a much shorter syntax for creating anonymous functions (see the `x -> x * 2` there?) among other things will be provided.

Comment: Or, if you know the numbers beforehand: `IntStream numbers = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 6); numbers.map(...)...` or `IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i + 2).limit(6).collect();`

Comment: Whether or not that is better depends on the situation; if you would start with creating that exact same List then yes, an IntStream created as suggested by you would be better. If you want to do stuff with it beforehand, probably not.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably preferable to use Guava (or Guava-like) style to implement this. Instead of for each method having a class that knows how to iterate, you can implement a `Function<From,To>` interface, and then use the appropriate utility class to apply the implementation.

For your example, in Guava:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

List<Integer> multipliedByTwo = Lists.transform(numbers, new Function<Integer, Integer>(){
      @Override
      public Integer apply(Integer input) {
          return input * 2;
      }
  }
```

This style will likely easily translate in Java 8 to lambda functions.

There's a great [article on functional idioms in Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained) with additional examples and suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'm aware of Guava, it's just that I'm trying to learn how to think functionally. I'm guessing my understanding is right?

Comment: Java 8: `numbers.stream().map(i->2*i).collect(toList())`

Comment: @toy The idea that you apply a function to every element of something vs. doing the work within a loop is on the right path.